# How can I adapt an oracle with occult mystery and aetherurgist archetype into a shaman?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conversion, shaman, oracle

I previously have a character who is an oracle, with occult mystery and [aetherurgist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/archetypes/oracle-archetypes---rite-publishing/aetherurgist) archetype.  After the release of hybrid classes in Pathfinder, I feel that shaman suits my original concept of this character better, but the closest spirit I can find that suits the character is bones, but seems more, uh, boney than ghosty.  Among the shaman traits I feel suit her better are the use of wisdom rather than charisma, hexes, and spirit companions.

So I would like some help and advice trying to make a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they converted some of the oracle mysteries over to shaman spirits, but not all. You therefore have a couple choices.

1. Convert it over yourself, and get your GM's permission.
2. Wait for the inevitable third party book that converts it over.
3. Reskin one of the other mysteries. "Shield of flying bones = shield of flying spirits." "Wracking pain in the bones = wracking pain in the soul." Done.

Also consider [one of the shaman archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/shaman) like "Possessed Shaman" or "Spirit Warden" depending on how exactly you see your character.

Comment: I was thinking of replacing the shaman spirit with aetherurgist and add on bones spirit for spirit companion featured.